# correct pattern to use: this or prototype

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

If I have an object function, when should I use `this.something` instead of `func.prototype.something` ?

Just to clarify:

```
function Person()
{
   this.walk=function(){...};
}
```

instead of:

```
function Person()
{}
Person.prototype.walk=function(){...};
```

When is convenient to use one form instead of the other? what are benefits and drawbacks of the two solutions ? Expecially in the case I'm using always `var person = new Person();`

Comment: Is this similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @Leigh yep correct, but I did not get exactly what's different in the case I'm using new person()

Comment: @Leigh ok this reply http://stackoverflow.com/a/310927/566608 in the duplicat equestion reply to me too, so I vot eto close that question too.

Answer (score 4):

The two pieces of code are really quite different, and achieve different goals.

The first sample involves a function that, when invoked, adds a property to the receiver object (the object referred to by `this`), or updates the value of that property if it already exists. Thus invoking that "Person" function with different receivers will update those objects separately, with each getting a property called "walk".  If "Person" is used as a constructor, then the newly-created object will similarly be updated directly.

The second sample adds a method to the *prototype* object of a function. When that function is subsequently called with `new`, the resulting new object will inherit properties from the prototype object. That means that such objects can be treated as if they actually have a property called "walk" that's a callable function. The property really does not exist directly on each constructed object, however; it's visible because of the role prototype objects play in JavaScript property lookups.

Comment: So much better described than me. +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this function on all instances of Person you need to use `prototype`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript) stackoverflow post.